# GMMap1.getZoom error

Tags: gmlib

I found a issue at GMMap.getZoom. It's a extra parentesis on executeScript function at GMMap.pas line 3071.

Original:
  if Assigned(FWC) and ExecuteScript('MapGetZoom(', '') then

Solution:
  if Assigned(FWC) and ExecuteScript('MapGetZoom', '') then

Comment: Thanks, I will modify it